# Not getting test class code coverage for If() condition

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

I tried several times to get the code coverage for the below test class now I need someone's help to get code coverage for red color coding in the Image
How can I ???

Here the below image shows the code coverage.

[image]

My Trigger

```
trigger customsolinsert on Price_Study__c (after update, after insert) {
// Find the existing (0 or 1) Custom_solution__c that reference Price_Study__c 
    Map<Id, Custom_solution__c> m = new Map<Id, Custom_solution__c>();
   list<Custom_solution__c> oblist=[ select id, Price_Study__c from Custom_solution__c where Price_Study__c in :Trigger.newMap.keySet() ];
    for (Custom_solution__c ob : oblist) {
        m.put(ob.Price_Study__c, ob);
    }  
// Insert or update the Custom_solution__c
List<Custom_solution__c> csol= new List<Custom_solution__c>();

for (Price_Study__c b : trigger.new) {
    // Get record to update
    Custom_solution__c ob = m.get(b.id);

  if(b.Analysis_Done_By__c<>Null){
 if (ob == null) {
        // If no record to update, add a record to be inserted
        ob = new Custom_solution__c(Price_Study__c = b.id);
    }
         ob.Price_Study__c=b.Id;       
         ob.Country__c=b.Country_of_Treatment__c;
         ob.Who_Deals__c=b.Analysis_Done_By__c;
         ob.Customer__c=b.Account_Name__c;
         ob.Product_line__c=b.Product_line__c;
         ob.Function_Focus__c=b.Function_Focus__c;
         ob.Comments__c=b.Generic_Comments__c;
         ob.Nbrs_Post__c=b.Nbrs_Post__c;
         ob.Series_Row_nbr__c=b.Series_Row_nbr__c;

    csol.add(ob);
   }
} 
upsert csol;
```

}

****Test Class****

```
@istest(isParallel=true)
  public class Testcustomsolinsert{
  @istest Static void Testcustomsol1(){

    Profile prof = [select id from profile where name='system Administrator'];
    List<User> lstUser = [Select u.Profile.Name, u.ProfileId, u.IsActive, u.Id From User u Where IsActive = true AND Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'];
    system.runAs(lstUser[0]){


   Account acc=new account(Name='NicoTestacc',BillingCountry='India');
    insert acc;

    Opportunity op1= new opportunity(Name='NicoTestOpp',CloseDate=date.today(),StageName='Qualification',Product_Type__c='DPI',Accountid=acc.Id);
    insert op1;
    System.assertEquals(op1.name,'NicoTestOpp');
    Price_Study__c ps=new Price_Study__c(Country_of_Treatment__c='India',Series_Row_nbr__c=3,
                                   Nbrs_Post__c=2,Analysis_Done_By__c=op1.OwnerId,
                                   Generic_Comments__c='asdfds',Function_Focus__c='sdad',
                                   Product_line__c='CMM');

    Insert Ps;

        Map<Id, Custom_solution__c> m = new Map<Id, Custom_solution__c>();             


        Custom_solution__c cs1=new Custom_solution__c(Price_Study__c=PS.Id,Country__c=Ps.Country_of_Treatment__c);

        Insert cs1;

        delete cs1;

     Custom_solution__c cs=new Custom_solution__c();


          cs.Price_Study__c=ps.Id;
          cs.Country__c=Ps.Country_of_Treatment__c;
          cs.Who_Deals__c=ps.Analysis_Done_By__c;
          cs.Customer__c=ps.Account_Name__c;
          cs.Product_line__c='Cmm';
          cs.Function_Focus__c=ps.Function_Focus__c;
          cs.Comments__c=ps.Generic_Comments__c;
          cs.Nbrs_Post__c=ps.Nbrs_Post__c;
          cs.Series_Row_nbr__c=ps.Series_Row_nbr__c;

  Insert cs;

        cs.Function_Focus__c=ps.Function_Focus__c;

  Update cs;
    }      
}
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, it's important to note that right now, your test class is not performing any tests. It's just executing the code. This is commonly referred to as a "smoke test". You need to write assertions to show that the behavior of your code is what is expected to have a true unit test.

In order to test the highlighted lines, you need to create test data that triggers that specific code path. Specifically, your test class needs to have your trigger fire on a `Price_Study__c` object that does not have a corresponding `Custom_solution__c` object and whose `Analysis_Done_By__c` field is `null`. You should then demonstrate that the behavior of your code is as expected by querying for `Custom_solution__c` and showing that the trigger correctly inserted a new object.